# <p> not validated - Alternatives for formatting paragraph?

Tags: html, css

following from a quick success with my last question, I've come up with another when validating.

I'm getting the 'document type does not allow 'P' here;....' error. In short i'm trying to write text inside a DIV and using the

tags to separate paragraphs. After a bit of searching i found the issue. It errors when the `<p>` is inside a `<font .....>`definition (because this is a block inside an inline) . So i tried using the `<h6>` tag instead (line 57) and defined it separately in CSS, which i thought would work as it is noted as a block-level element.

Ideally i want a way of initially defining the text attributes, leave it open for all paragraphing etc.. and then close it at the end. - rather than having to re-enter  every time a new `<p>` is created.

Again - any help would be much appreciated.- Advice on my layout and how it could be improved.

The Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    a:link {
        color: #000;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: #666;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: #F00;
    }
    </style>
    <link href="CSS/dg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>


    <div id="dgbackground"> </div>
    <div id="textwrapper"> 

    <div id="spec">
    <h4>Specification</h4>   
     <div id="specAQA"><a href="http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-9030-W-SP-14.PDF" target="_blank"><img src="images/gcse images/AQA_logo_RGB.jpg" width="150" height="50" alt="aqa link"/></a></div>

     <div id="specDOC"><a href="documents/gcse/dg spec.docx"><img src="images/DOC.png" width="100%" height="100%" alt="word" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <br /> <br />
    <h2>The Development Gap</h2>



    <div id="contents">

        <div id="extras">

        <font face="cambria" color="black" size="5px"> 
        <p>
        <strong> EXTRAS </strong>
        </p>
            <p> 'Cool Geography' <a href="http://www.coolgeography.co.uk/GCSE/AQA/Development_Gap/Development%20Gap.htm" target="_blank">Website</a>
        </p>

        <p> BBC Bitesize <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/geography/development/" target="_blank"><img src="images/bitesize1..png" width="35" height="25" alt="bitesize" /></a> 
        </p>
        </font>
        </div>

    <h6> 
    <p> 
     <a href="re1.html">1. Contrasts using different measures of development to include
    GNP, GNI per head, Human Development Index (HDI), birth
    and death rates, infant mortality, people per doctor, literacy rate, access to safe water and life expectancy.
        <br /> Correlation between the different measures.
    Limitations/ways of using a single development measure.
        <br /> Different ways of classifying different parts of the world.
        <br /> The relationship between quality of life and standard of living. Different perceptions of acceptable quality of life in different parts of the world. Attempts made by people in the
    poorer part of the world to improve their own quality of life.</a>

    </p>


    <p> 
    <a href="re2.html">2. Environmental factors – the impact of natural hazards. A case study of a natural hazard.
    Economic factors – global imbalance of trade between different parts of the world.
    Social factors – differences in the quantity and quality of water available on peoples’ standards of living.
    Political influences – the impact of unstable governments.</a>
    </p>

    <p>
      <a href="re3.html">3. The imbalance in the pattern of world trade and the attempts to reduce it.
    The contributions of Fair Trade and Trading Groups.
    The reduction in debt repayments through debt abolition and conservation swaps.
    The advantages and disadvantages of different types of aid for donor and recipient countries.
    The role of international aid donors in encouraging sustainable development.
    A case study of one development project.</a>
    </p>

    <p>
    4. (Case Study)
    Conditions leading to different levels of development in two contrasting countries of the EU.
    The attempts by the EU to reduce these different levels of development.
    </p>  
    </h6>

    </div><!-- end contents-->


    </div> <!--end textwrapper--> 


    </body>
    </html>
```

The CSS:

```
h2 {
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 65px;
    margin: 0;
    Padding:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
h5 {
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #666;
    margin: 0;
    Padding:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
h6 {
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #000;    
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 3px #333;

}

h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: 40px;    
}
img{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #000;
border-radius: 3px;
}
#textwrapper {
    max-width: 1300px;
    min-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}   


#dgbackground {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #F00;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/gcse%20images/dg.jpg);
}
#dgtitle {
    height: auto;
    width: 150x;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
#spec {
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    float:right
}

#specAQA {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 45px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#specDOC {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top: 45px;
    margin: 10px;
}
#contents {
    max-width: 1500px;
    min-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    height: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#centerIMG {
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

#floatrightIMG {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#floatleftIMG {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#extras {
    float:right;
    width: 250px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align:center
}
```

Comment: The first heading in your document is an h4. The second is h2. Please read http://webaim.org/techniques/semanticstructure/#contentstructure

Comment: Yes, got it. This was to do with the order in which i put the DIVS inside the source code. - will amend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Quentin said, using the font element is pointless.

You should create a paragraph class whereas:

```
<font face="cambria" color="black" size="5px"><p><strong>EXTRAS</strong></p>
   <p>'Cool Geography'<a href="http://www.coolgeography.co.uk/GCSE/AQA/Development_Gap/Development%20Gap.htm" target="_blank">Website</a></p>
   <p>BBC Bitesize <a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/geography/development/" target="_blank"><img src="images/bitesize1..png" width="35" height="25" alt="bitesize" /></a> 
   </p>
</font>
```

Should be a paragraph style like:

```
<p class="yourclassname">Enter paragraph text</p>
<p class="yourclassname">Enter paragraph text</p>
```

Then apply the desired font and style to the class in your CSS:

```
.yourclassname {
   font-family: cambria;
   color: black;
   font-size: 5px;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: thank you to both Quentin & ben.kaminski. I have now removed the <font...> and simply added styling the the <p> tag in CSS, which is fine as all the <p> content needs to be the same anyway. And now it all Validates !

Answer (score 4):

`<font>` was superseded by CSS in [1996](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/). Stop using it.

You can't put a paragraph inside a heading.

Use *appropriate* markup.

If you want to style a paragraph, then apply CSS to a `<p>`.

If you want to group a bunch of paragraphs together, then pick [an appropriate element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sections) such as `<section>`, `<article>`, or `<aside>`. If HTML doesn't have an element that describes the reason for the grouping, then use the generic block level element: `<div>`.

If you don't want to style all elements of that type the same way, then add whatever classes and ids you need to write a [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) to target the elements you want to affect.